# javafx change Opacity when typing

Tags: javafx

I have a primaryStage with opacity. When mouse intered in a window - opacity 1. When mouse exit from window - 0.8.
Part of code:

```
  scene.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
            primaryStage.setOpacity(1);
        }
    });

    scene.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
            primaryStage.setOpacity(0.3);
        }
    });
```

If I type in the text field in the application and not the mouse on the window, the scene set opacity 0.8.
How can i set opacity 1 when typing text?
Please give me advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it opaque when a key is pressed with:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> primaryStage.setOpacity(1));
```

If you want it to revert to semi-transparent when the user "stops" typing, it's a little trickier, since all you can handle are individual key presses. You need a timer that resets the opacity if no key is pressed for some amount of time. E.g.:

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1.0));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> primaryStage.setOpacity(0.8));

scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
    pause.playFromStart();
    primaryStage.setOpacity(1);
});
```

Comment: James_D, Thanks a lot!